# AutoMapper 6.0.2 Resolve destination member using a custom value resolver

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use a Custom Value Resolver to delegate mapping of a list of Assignees from the Entity class to the service class. Below is the class where I do my mapping

```
using AutoMapper;
using WebApi2Book.Common.TypeMapping;
using WebApi2Book.Data.Entities;

namespace WebApi2Book.Web.Api.AutoMappingConfiguration
{
    public class TaskEntityToTaskAutoMapperTypeConfigurator : IAutoMapperTypeConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<Task, Models.Task>()
                  .ForMember(opt => opt.Links, x => x.Ignore())
                  .ForMember(opt => opt.Assignees, 
                  x => x.ResolveUsing<TaskAssigneesResolver1>());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The Configure() method is implemented from the IAutoMapperTypeConfigurator interface

CustomResolver

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using WebApi2Book.Common.TypeMapping;
using WebApi2Book.Data.Entities;
using WebApi2Book.Web.Common;
using User = WebApi2Book.Web.Api.Models.User;
using Task = WebApi2Book.Data.Entities.Task;

namespace WebApi2Book.Web.Api.AutoMappingConfiguration
{
    public class TaskAssigneesResolver : IValueResolver<Task, List<User>>//Task, List<User>, List<User>>
    {
        public IAutoMapper AutoMapper
        {
            get { return WebContainerManager.Get<IAutoMapper>(); }
        }

       // protected override List<User> ResolveCore(Task source)
       // {
       //     return source.Users.Select(x => AutoMapper.Map<User>(x)).ToList();
       // }

        public List<User> Resolve(Task source)
        {
            return source.Users.Select(x => AutoMapper.Map<User>(x)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Models.Task class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApi2Book.Web.Api.Models
{
    public class Task
    {
        private List<Link> _links;
        public long? TaskId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CompletedDate { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public List<User> Assignees { get; set; }
        public List<Link> Links
        {
            get { return _links ?? (_links = new List<Link>()); }
            set { _links = value; }
        }

        public void AddLink(Link link)
        {
            Links.Add(link);
        }
    }
}
```

Entities.Task class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApi2Book.Data.Entities
{
    public class Task : IVersionedEntity
    {
        private readonly IList<User> _users = new List<User>();
        public virtual long TaskId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? CompletedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<User> Users
        {
            get { return _users; }
        }

        public virtual byte[] Version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is supposed to be a fairly straightforward mapping where it ignores the links because they aren't present in the source and it delegates the Assignees mapping to the Resolver.

Error:

The type 'TaskAssigneesResolver' cannot be used as type parameter 'TValueResolver' in the generic type or method `'AutoMapper.IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource,TDestination,TMember>.ResolveUsing<TValueResolver>()'`.

There is no implicit reference conversion from `'TaskAssigneesResolver'` to `'AutoMapper.IValueResolver<Data.Models.Task, Entities.Task, object>'`.

I suspect I am misunderstanding the IValueResolver interface. Please give me possible solutions: